# Fullcalendar Gem Rails Wont Display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

FullCalendar appears blank how can i display the calendar. It seems that there are few guides or documentation for the fullcalendar on rails. I can't seem to pinpoint what's wrong. There are no errors just displays a blank page.

View

```
<div class="calendar"></div>
```

Channel/full_calendar.js

```
var initialize_calendar;
initialize_calendar = function() {
    $('.calendar').each(function(){
        var calendar = $(this);
        calendar.fullCalender({});
    })
};
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', initialize_calendar);
```

Application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require moment
//= require fullcalendar
//= require jquery-dcjqaccordion
//= require_tree .
```

Application.css.scss

```
 *= require fullcalendar
 *= require daterangepicker
```

Comment: does your browser js console return any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing

```
//= require turbolinks
```

In your `application.js`. Without it the `'turbolinks:load'` won't fire.

If you plan on using Turbolinks you will also need to destroy your fullCalendar objects before navigation, as [mentioned here](https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails#usage-together-with-turbolinks-version-5).

```
function eventCalendar() {
  return $('#event_calendar').fullCalendar({ ***your FullCalendar config***});
};

function clearCalendar() {
  $('#event_calendar').fullCalendar('delete'); // In case delete doesn't work.
  $('#event_calendar').html('');
};

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', eventCalendar);
$(document).on('turbolinks:before-cache', clearCalendar)
```

Comment: I added turbolinks and throws me an error of Uncaught TypeError: calendar.fullCalender is not a function

Comment: You have a typo. Calendar has an `a` instead of an `e`. Should be `calendar.fullCalendar({})`